# Best practices for rolling your own SQL reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, report, sql-server-2012

I've been spending the latter part of my afternoon looking on Google for good references/information/documentation/best practices for rolling your own C# (IIS 7.5) reports from a SQL 2012 backend and have come up empty handed.

What I want to avoid is leveraging the SQL Reporting Services as I've run into nothing but problems with this utility.

Specifically, I want to create various management-type reports for monthly and year to date reports.

[Here's a sample of the type of reporting I'm looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454370/tsql-sum-by-group-for-monthly-reports)

Here's the catch, due to company policy I'm not allowed to leverage open source software/utilities, nor am I looking for pay 3rd party reporting software.

Comment: SSRS is tailor made for the kind of reports you're describing. Sure, it has a few quirks here and there but nothing that major for basic management type reports. Why are you dismissing it so quickly?

Comment: I agree with the general feedback here that you shouldn't dismiss SSRS too quickly. And although I may be stating the obvious, a company policy that says "we don't have any money for this but we can spend lots of your time" is obviously flawed. Before you start re-inventing the wheel you should make every effort to find an existing solution, even if it costs money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to avoid is leveraging the SQL Reporting Services as I've run into nothing but problems with this utility.

What sort of issues? I've used SSRS extensively, like anything it has got some negatives here and there, but with experience you learn what they are and how to avoid them.

I would advocate that you use SSRS for this project, it's a no-brainer. You get it for free, and it does everything you're asking for and more.

The approach I've used in the past is to carefully analyze the business requirements for each report and identify the commonalities in layout and parameters between them, then create a template report with the common features and themes which is then tailored for each specific report. A rule-of-thumb I use is it takes on average three days to fully develop one complex report (this includes data retrieval and shaping as well as the actual report layout).

With SSRS you could also implement the ReportBuilder feature which allows users to create their own reports - a great selling point for management. SSRS can also be used to generate reports from Analysis Services as well as standard OLTP databases.

Comment: For one, when I leveraged the Visual Studio 2012 version of these tools it instaled something on my IIS 7.5 web server that rendered the entire site useless and inaccessable.  Secondly, there's no way to trace any errors in the reports and in some cases won't tell you where any errors in the code or reports are at when the T-SQL code works in the Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I’d give SSRS a try before everything else, especially if those are simple reports.

Other alternative is to develop your own simple reporting system. Depending on how many reports are needed and how frequently these are going to be changed you can start with something really simple like creating a web app where each page will be for one specific report.

Just encapsulate all SQL code into stored procedure, add parameters to the page and display results in a grid view.

Now if you have hundreds of reports they you will most definitely need something more sophisticated.